# Get hasMany relationship with Eloquent Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model, eloquent

I have two tables with this schmea:

```
mysql> show columns from table_1;
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------
| id          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_incre
| id_world    | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL                |
| key         | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |
| name        | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |
| description | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |
| level       | int(11)          | NO   |     | 0                   |
| created_at  | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
| updated_at  | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and

```
mysql> show columns from table_2;
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------
------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra
      |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------
| id           | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_incr
| key          | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |
| level        | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL                |
| name         | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |
| description  | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |
| price        | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL                |
| amount       | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL                |
| created_at   | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
| updated_at   | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------
30 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I want to get all fields "from table_2 where table_2.key = table_1.key AND table_2.level = 10" is this the right way with the hasMany option in my model?

my normal query looks like this:

```
SELECT A.key AS p_key,
       A.name AS p_key,
       A.description AS p_desc,
       A.level AS p_level,
       B.key AS r_key,
       B.level AS r_level,
       B.name AS r_name,
       B.description AS r_desc 
FROM 
       table_1 AS A,
       table_2 AS B
WHERE 
       B.key = A.key AND
       B.level = '1'
```

Comment: Using Eloquent relation with non-unique fields as keys may/will result in unexpected behaviour. You shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To build `hasMany` relationship using those tables, you need to create two models first, for example:

```
class TableOne extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'table_1';

    public function tableTwoItems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('TableTwo', 'table_2.key', 'table_1.key')
                    ->where('table_2.level', 1);
    }
}

class TableTwo extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'table_2';
}
```

Once you created these models in your `app/models` directory then you may use something like this:

```
$result = TableOne::with('tableTwoItems')->get();
```

To select the items/fields, you may use something like this:

```
$result = TableOne::with(array('tableTwoItems' => function($query){
    $query->select('table_2.key as k2', 'table_2.name as name2', 'more...');
}))->select('table_1.key as k1', 'table_1.name as name1', 'more...')->get();
```

You may access them like:

```
$result->first()->tableTwoItems->first();
```

Or you may loop `$result` and also you may loop the related items using nested loop. For example:

```
foreach($result as $tableOneItem)

    echo $tableOneItem->name;

    foreach($tableOneItem->tableTwoItems as $tabletwoItem)

        echo $tabletwoItem->name;

    endforeach;

endforeach;
```

Try to use different field names in both table's `key` and make them unique as well. Read the [Eloquent Relation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships) documentation for more.

Comment: 1 You don't need to use prefixed fields `table_1.key` in `hasMany` definition. 2 your 2nd example `with()->select()` is wrong, remember the tables are not joined, so it will cause `unknown column` error. 3 You don't need to use `PK` for the relation, and in this case it's not table's `PK`, nor is it unique - see my comment to the question.

Comment: Thanks mate @JarekTkaczyk_deczo_, I've updated the answer and I'm not sure how did I make that mistake :-)

Comment: Me neither, probably you just needed a coffee or something ;)

Comment: lol... Well, actually it was 4:30 am so yes, you are right about the coffee :-) @JarekTkaczyk_deczo_